# VMWare Server Not Working in Bridged Mode

Tags: vmware-server

I have a Win 7 x64 Host with VMWare Server 2.02 installed.  On a previous install of Win7 on this machine, I had everything working fine with VMWare server.  This time, my virtual machines can not get a dhcp address.  I have them set to use bridging.

I found some posts mentioning that a wrong adapter could get bridged.  I do have multiple adapters because virtual box is currently installed.  So I explicitly set vm0 to bind to my physical adapter.

If I set an IP address manually, I can ping IPs local to the host from the guest, but nothing else on the same LAN.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox was also bridged on the adapter.  Apparently they can't both do that at the same time.  I turned that off, rebooted the box, and vmware could attach properly.